# cpu max frequency is actually the base frequency

Tags: cpu, frequency

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.50 GHz
  available frequency steps:  2.50 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.30 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 2.50 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 2.50 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

my cpu:

```
    Processor Number i5-13400

CPU Specifications

    Total Cores 10
    # of Performance-cores 6
    # of Efficient-cores 4
    Total Threads 16
    Max Turbo Frequency 4.60 GHz
    Performance-core Max Turbo Frequency 4.60 GHz
    Efficient-core Max Turbo Frequency 3.30 GHz
    Performance-core Base Frequency 2.50 GHz
    Efficient-core Base Frequency 1.80 GHz
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: Please do not use comments to add info that belongs in the question. Use the edit feature and add the info to the question.

Comment: Are you forcing the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver? The intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver is expected by default. It appears as though turbo is disabled. For the acpi-cpufreq driver check via: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost`